# Keyboard become laggy after a while

Tags: ios, swift, hybrid-mobile-app

I am building a hybrid app with Meteor & Xcode. I have one viewcontroller with a webview. The more you use the app (about after a few minuteS) the keyboard becomes sluggish. In other words, the keyboard pulls up and down with lag, which becomes worse the more you use the app. What could cause this problem?

Comment: Run Instruments and profile the app to see whether it's a CPU or memory issue.

Comment: Could it be because it was not on the main thread?

Comment: @user523234 if that was the case, how would I be able to resolve it?

Comment: Not familiar with Meteor and Swift either but in Object-c, you can put this line where you add the webview to the view to see what thread it is running on: NSLog(@"%s currentthread:%@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, [NSThread currentThread]);